# how to use remote validation in class library in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I try to do a remote validation like the following

```
[Remote("VerifyEmail", "Home", "Account")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

My models are in a separate class Library
How can I use the remote to connect to my web project?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My models are in a separate class Library How can I use the remote to
> connect to my web project?

Below is a demo, you can refer to it.

In HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult VerifyEmail(string Email)
        {
            var existingEmails = new[] { "jane@test.com", "claire@test.com", "dave@test.com" };
            var valid = !existingEmails.Contains(Email);
            return new JsonResult(valid);    
        }
    }
```

Index view:

```
@model ClassLibrary1.Class1
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
<form method="post" asp-action="VerifyEmail">
    <input asp-for="Email" /> 
    <span asp-validation-for="Email"></span><br>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
@section scripts{ 
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/dist/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
}
```

Class1 in a separate class Library:

```
public class Class1
    {
        [Remote("VerifyEmail", "Home")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

result:

[image]